# jQuery live in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function, live

JS:

```
var count = 0;

jQuery(function () {
    $('.input').live('input', function () {

    //any instructions here
    count++;
    $('.count').text(count);

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea class="input" /></textarea>

<br /> <span class="count"></span>
```

I want to do the same in IE.
This works in all browsers but not in IE...

I can't use `live('keyup')` because this must works "on paste".

Also `live('paste')` doesn't work in IE.

I want to execute instructions when type a character (with keyboard) or paste a character (right click > paste [with mouse]).

http://jsfiddle.net/4LDJG/4/

Comment: what do u want to do exactly. do u want how many time use focus on textarea ?

Comment: Exactly what is now but work in IE.
When type a character or pase a character to do the stuff inside the function.

Comment: No, textarea can be an input. I want to execute instructions when type a character or pase a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use setinterval function

```
$(function (){

    function jm(){
       var val=$('textarea').val();
       var jj=val.split("");
       $('.count').text(jj.length);
    }
    setInterval(jm,100);
});
```

Comment: check it once again, i have change my answer

Comment: i just change setTimeout to setInterval

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is deprecated in jQuery - maybe using one of the following might work better across browsers

```
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<textarea class="input" onchange="evaluate(this)" /></textarea>
<br /> <span class="count"></span>
```

js:

```
function evaluate(sender){
  var value = $(sender).val();
  var arrayWords = value.split(' ');
  $('.count').text(arrayWords.length);
}
```